# How cab I byte patch exe using C#

Tags: c#, assembly, ida

How can I use C# to alter an exe file content?
Say I managed to generate a diff file between the original exe (org.exe) and the altered one (mod.exe) and I want to create a C# code which will read the org.exe file and the diff file and generate a new exe file.

Currently the content of the diff file looks like this:

```
000000000003E9A6: 0F 90
000000000003E9A7: 85 90
000000000003E9A8: C8 90
000000000003E9A9: 01 90
000000000003E9AA: 00 90
000000000003E9AB: 00 90
```

In the above example I want to replace certain commands with NOPs.
I also saw this:
https://github.com/LogosBible/bsdiff.net/issues/9
But I can't make it work.

I know there are apps which can do this but I want to add this to my C# code.

Thanks

Comment: You only need to overwrite the bytes at those offsets (e.g. write a byte with value 0x90 at offset 0x3e9a6). This is trivial in any programming language as it is in C#. Make a [mcve] if you need help with a specific issue.

Comment: You could read the file into a byte array, update those specific bytes, and write to a new file (or overwrite the original)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you want to do this to make partial upgrades easier, it will fail and actually make things *much* worse. You can modify random bytes on any file, but that would end up triggering any antivirus, invalidate any signed assemblies or publisher signatures. Patching isn't easily reversible or fixable either. If something goes wrong, you need to find out what patches were applied and reverse them. Which means you need to keep track of the original file anyway. There's a reason byte patching isn't used

Comment: The *safe* way used by all installers, OSs, and package managers in all languages, is to deploy applications as packages of components (files, registry settings, etc). When a package is deployed, the older package version is kept so that if something goes wrong, the system can revert to it. Either all package contents are deployed succesfully, or all are rolled back. That's how Windows Installer works since the 1990s. User documents and settings aren't part of the deployment package and are typically stored separately.

Comment: If you still want binary patching, any diff tool will do. Some are more efficient than others. The most naive way would be to compare files byte by byte and write the offsets and values of any differences. There are tools and algorithms that can generate such patches in a much more efficient way though, eg the RSync and RDiff algorithms and implementations like [OctoDiff](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Octodiff/) which is used by Octopus Deploy

Comment: Many projects exist for this.  e.g. https://github.com/jmacd/xdelta.  An easy way to do what you asked would be to copy the whole file, then open the copy (or keep it open) and make a system call like NtWriteFile to write some bytes at a given offset, with a given length.